# kubectl get resources by label with OR operator

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I know we can do the following commands:

- `kubectl get pods -l app==<kafka>` gets pods with kafka label
- `kubectl get pods -l app!=<kafka>` gets pods without kafka label
- `kubectl get pods -l app=kafka,env=staging` gets pods with both kafka and staging labels

But what about if I want to list all the pods which have either `kafka` or `zookeeper` label. Something like `-l app==kafka||zookeeper`.

Is this even possible with `-l` kubectl option...?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
kubectl get pods -l 'app in (kafka, zookeeper)'
```

See: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/#api